# Where can I find massive and high dimensional survival datasets

Tags: data-request, medical, programming

I am working on developing some high-dimensional survival analysis methods with R, but I do not know where to find such high-dimensional survival datasets.

Could anyone tell me where to find such datasets, for examples the data used in:

- ["Predicting survival from microarray data—a comparative study"](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/23/16/2080.full.pdf)
- Dutch breast cancer data van Houwelingen et al. (2006), 295*24885
- DLBCL data Rosenwald et al. (2002), 240*7399

Or any other massive high dimensional survival datasets?

Comment: Have you requested the data from the authors of those papers? That would be the first thing to try.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but no reply so far. I will try again later.

Comment: The joy of academic research…

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the "survival" statistical package on R, you should also be familiar with the free datasets that Rstudio comes packaged with.

Check out this [webpage](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html) that lists all datasets that come preinstalled. Searching for "survival" should yield quite a few different tables that will be readily available to download.

While many of them only contain only a few dimensions, some provide more granularity - but not sure if this meets your requirements. Do you have a more thorough list of requirements (N number of dimensions... X number of rows) that you can specify?